# How do I display UTF-8 characters in google app engine's logs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm currently using Java and I print my string using System.out.println(myString);

However, when I look at my server logs on the google app engine dashboard, I see a bunch of question marks (???) in place of where special characters (in my particular case, emoticons) would be.

The string is obtained directly from the payload of the request.

The payload of the request is being read as:

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    String body = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: but I don't see any usage of `System.out.println(myString);` in this code example

Comment: This is the code to show how I read the payload body (which contains the utf-8 encoded characters) from the HTTPServletRequest. I then pass the 'body' variable to other methods and I log it there.

Comment: If it helps you can assume there's a System.out.println(body) right after the last line of the example above.